# Play throws RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following Play controller:

```
package controllers

import models.{Page, DB}
import play.api._
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc._

class Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

  val pageForm: Form[Page] = Form {
    mapping (
      "url" -> text
    )(Page.apply)(Page.unapply)
  }

  def addPage = Action { implicit request =>
    val page = pageForm.bindFromRequest.get
    DB.save(page)
    Redirect(routes.Application.index)
  }

  def getPages = Action {
    val page = DB.query[Page].fetch
    Ok(Json.toJson(page))
  }
}
```

This controller accesses this model:

```
package models

import java.net.URL

import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Page(url: String) {
  var content: String = new URL(url).getContent().toString;
}

object Page {
  implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Page]
}
```

And is stored in the database like this:

```
package models

import sorm._

object DB extends Instance(entities = Seq(Entity[Page]()), url="jdbc:h2:mem:test")
```

I create a new instance of the model from the UI like this:

```
 <form action="@routes.Application.addPage" method="post">
        <input name="url" type="text">
        <button>Add Page</button>
    </form>
```

However, when I submit the form from the browser, I get this:

```
    [error] - play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Cannot invoke the action
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:498) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:537) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Iteratee.scala:537) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.13.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
```

My `build.sbt` file:

```
name := """ScalaWeb"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.19",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value force(),
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.148"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

scalacOptions += "-Ylog-classpath"
```

The error message isn't very descriptive. What is wrong about this code?

Comment: Please, post the complete stack trace.

Comment: I added the full stack trace.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your `build.sbt` Probably you forgot to add h2 dependency:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.118",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.168"
)
```

And use name `Db` instead `DB`. Big `DB` is a part of play database API.

Comment: Indeed, the h2 dependency was not there. Now I have added it(as you can see in my updated post) but the same error message appears.